# How to use point sprite API in Android NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I want use point sprite (OpenGLES Extension) API in Android NDK(r4).
right here
  int att[] = {0,0,1};
  glPointParameterxv( GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION, att );

But, doesn't work it.

Answer (score 1):

Functions suffixed with 'xv' and 'x' receives fixed-point data. You can try:

```
GLFixed[] att = {0, 0, 1 << 16};
```

Comment: I tried it.

But, displayed error message like "called unimplemented OpenGL ES API".

After all, is not android NDK supported point sprite....?

Comment: What does glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) say about ARB_point_sprite?

Comment: Yes, extension API.

It is defined in Android NDK, but displayed "called unimplemented OpenGL ES API" to console.

Comment: It is defined in the headers, but that doesn't not mean it's supported by the graphics chip. That's only detectable in runtime, if you call that glGetString function I wrote about.

Comment: glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) on HTC-03A(OS1.6).

07-05 23:57:58.935: INFO/GETSTRING:(552): GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_extended_texture_coordinate_data_formats GL_ATI_imageon_misc GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture

Comment: GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_matrix_palette GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_vertex_buffer_object GL_QUALCOMM_vertex_buffer_object GL_QUALCOMM_direct_texture 
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
>>GL_OES_point_sprite
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　


It is supported with the graphics chip, aren't you?

But, displayed "called unimplemented OpenGL ES API".

Is Point sprite API blocked in SDK or NDK....?